# Sphinx search engine and related tags

Tags: tags, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx search engine to index all my Intranet documents using tags. With that I don't have any trouble to find specific documents with one ore more tags.

I want to go further with a new feature like the StackOverflow "related tags" feature.

Does anybody know the best way to do this with Sphinx ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You run a boolean OR query on all terms in the document you want to find related items for. It can be fairly slow because all documents in the database has to be ranked on similarity, unless you limit the search using and:ed terms. See my text here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121266/efficient-item-similarity-search-using-sphinx